# Explaining ENVI equations?

Tags: envi

Could you please explain the meaning of this equation:

```
(b1 le 0) * 0 + (b1 ge 10000) * 1 + (b1 gt 0 et b1 lt 10000) * float (b1) / 10000 b1.
```

What do `ge`, `gl` etc mean?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

- `ge` means "greater or equal" (i.e. `>=`)
- `gt` means "greater than" (i.e. strictly greater, `>`)
- `le` means "lower or equal" (i.e. `<=`)
- `lt` means "lower than" (i.e. strictly lower, `<`)

`et` is probably a mistake (French for `and`).

Answer (score 2):

These are relational Operators. See here: https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/Relational_Operators.html

I'm not sure what et stands for, but using these, the equation becomes:

`(b1 <= 0) * 0 + (b1 >= 10000) * 1 + (b1 > 0 et b1 < 10000) * float (b1) / 10000 b1.`